# Custom interceptor returns but request doesn't hit function in controller

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am developing spring boot project. I have a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, in where I have some logic to intercept and check request data in `preHandle(...)`.

```
public class MyCustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

    // I only override the preHandle(...)
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse  response){
    //my custom logic here.

    // if a condition is not met, I return false, my understanding is that it would stop this request from proceeding forward
    if(conditionNotMet) {
       log.info("Condition NOT met, returns false!")
       response.setStatus(400);
       return false;
    }

    log.info("Condition met, returns true!")
    // otherwise, returns true
    return true;
    }
}
```

In above interceptor's `preHandle()`, I have some custom logic, then I check if certain condition is not met, I return false to stop proceeding forward the request, otherwise I return true there. My understanding is that if I return true eventually, the request would hit the corresponding rest controller.

The interceptor is registered and functional well:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private MyCustomInterceptor myCustomInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(myCustomInterceptor);
    }
}
```

I have a rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/myservice/")
public class MyController {
   @PostMapping(value = "add_note")
    public MyResponse addNote(@Valid @RequestBody AddNotePayload payload) {
        // I see logs in interceptor, it returns true but I don't see this log
        log.info(" Start adding note...");

       ...
}
```

The URL maps to the `addNote(...)` function of above controller is `POST http//localhost:8080/api/myservice/add_note`.  When I fire to this endpoint on Postman, I see the logs in `preHandle()` of my interceptor that the condition there is met and `preHandler()` returns `true`. Because it returns true there, so I expected that the request would be proceeded forward to controller level, but I don't see the log in `addNote()` of `MyController`. Why? What could be the reason?

Comment: Instead of auto wiring MyCustomInterceptor just use new MyCustomInterceptor().